# using rsync (or other tool) to correct file time stamps between two systems

Tags: files, rsync, backup

I have two systems (A, B) which have the same file structure. Files are identical but in one of the places (B), the file timestamps are incorrect. The problem is that most of the timestamps in B are set to newer date than A. Is there a way to correct this with rsync (or some other tool)?

The problem is that if I do `rsync -azEX --delete A B` no modification is done on the B side since the dates show that the files are newer (and transferring the whole file structure is an option that I want to avoid).

Comment: If you know the timestamp you want to apply to the files, you could use `find [...] -exec touch [args]`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Each file has a different one and they need to match those on the remote system (connection over ssh).

Comment: On A use `find` and `stat` to generate `touch` commands; execute the commands on B. Read `man find stat touch bash`. There are several "timestamps" associated with each file, and you may have to `bash` the `stat` output for `touch`.

Comment: The first  thing I would do is sync the clocks on the two machines using ntpdate. (You may have to shutdown ntp if it's running on the machine using ntpdate - both ntp and ntpdate use the same socket and only one can use it at time. Then turn on ntp.) Add the  -I flag (ignore timestamps)  to rsync once to ensure you have a complete backup. Then apply the answer by @Jim L.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that your `A` and `B` represent different systems rather than parts of the local filesystem, `rsync` will only transfer metadata. It will read the files on both sides, though, to ensure the checksums are correct, but will only transfers parts of files that are different:

```
rsync -azX /some/path/ user@remote:/target/path
```

If you can guarantee that the content is the same on both sides, you can switch off time checking but still carry across the timestamp value. This will read file metadata on both sides, but not file content.

If files have different sizes `rsync` will perform a checksum (again on both sides) to see what parts of the file need to be transferred, but otherwise as stated above, for files of the same size the file content will not be considered.

```
rsync -azX --size-only /some/path/ user@remote:/target/path
```

As a worked example, I have a 600MB file that was transferred from London to Amsterdam, with an extremely slow (1Mbit/s) link out of London. Obviously the original copy took quite some time. I copied the file and then reset the timestamp. Suggestion #1 takes around 10 seconds. Suggestion #2 takes less than 1 second. Neither transfers any of the file content.

Comment: The second command did what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no broken symlinks in either A or B, I would recommend [`mtree`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree):

```
$ mtree -Pcp A -k time | ssh hostB mtree -Ptp B
```

This will create a tree specification based on the timestamps found within file heirarchy `A`, and use that specification to set the timestamps on the corresponding files in heirarchy `B` residing on host `hostB`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there might be a bug in `mtree` but it does not handle well russian alphabet (probably not supporting `utf8` properly) which then gives inconsistent results, eg. some files in the structure where the file with russian alphabet is are not set the time correctly, one has to go to the directory manually and run the command specially there. If `mtree` worked correctly, it would be a great tool (also, e.g. `-t` is not documented in the man pages suggesting probably a poor development of the tool.