# rsync seems to ignore modified time

Tags: rsync, backup

This question is based on my previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646415/using-rsync-or-other-tool-to-correct-file-time-stamps-between-two-systems?noredirect=1#comment1211376_646415).
I have a file structure identical on two machines (A and B). The files are identical but differ in timestamps (time is correct on A, wrong on B). The above mentioned question was dealing with that.

However, i tried the following trick. I changed the modified times of all files in the structure to 1.1.1970 on the machine B by:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print "touch --no-create --no-dereference -m -t  \"197001010000\" \"" $1 "\""}' files.txt > commands2.sh
parallel < "commands2.sh"
```

Note that the file `files.txt` was generated on the machine A and has lines each of which is:
`"$1"\t"$2"` where `$1` gives the absolute path to the file and `$2` has the modified date as output by `stat -c %y $1`.

I verified by `stat` that the file dates are indeed set to 1970. I used Krusader directory sync to test and Krusader decided to correctly copy the data from A to B.

Then I test `rsync`
first `A -> B`:

```
rsync -azEX --dry-run --itemize-changes --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 --delete --exclude-from=/home/user/.rsync-transport-in-ssh.rules  /home/user user@remote:/home/user/
```

the output is empty. Then `B -> A`

```
rsync -azEX --dry-run --itemize-changes --info=BACKUP1,DEL1,NAME1,REMOVE1 --delete --exclude-from=/home/user/.rsync-transport-in-ssh.rules user@remote:/home/user/ /home/user
```

the output is full of transfers that are supposed to be made but this is completely incorrect because all data on B are dated to 1970.

So the question is two fold, 1) what does really `rsync` use to decide where to copy? and 2) is there any way to enforce the behaviour the way i want to?

Note that i suspect that `rsync` is actually using the file status change date because those I did not update on `B` and in many cases those are ahead of those on `A`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. what does really rsync use to decide where to copy?
> 2. is there any way to enforce the behaviour the way i want to?

1. `rsync` uses a number of different approaches to determine whether or not to copy file content. For example,

   - comparison of file size and timestamps
   - checksum of content
   - locality of source and destination (i.e. are they in the same filesystem or on separate servers)

   Notice that `rsync` differentiates between transferring file metadata (data about the file, such as permissions, ownership, timestamps, etc.) and file content. Furthermore, in cases involving two systems, `rsync` can use checksums to determine which parts of the file content have changed so that it only needs to transfer the changed parts rather than the entire file.

Copy a file to a remote server. Now modify the local copy so that there is one *extra* byte at the *beginning*. Use `rsync` to copy the file and you'll find it transfers a stream of block checksums with just one block of data. In my example of a 600MB file with a source and destination limited by a 1Mbit/s upload, adding a single byte to the front of one of the instances, the "copy" of the source file took 20 seconds, with an average effective speed of 415Mbit/s.

2. Answered in [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646459/100397)

Comment: Do you have an explanation why `rsync` behaves as described, that is, after resetting the modified date on all the files on one side, it will not overwrite them and actually, if you switch source and destination, would overwrite the "newer" destination files?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. The closest I can find is that with the `--update` (`-u`) flag, files that are newer on the destination are skipped, i.e. `rsync` will update older files but will not replace newer files.